# ZonedDateTime parse exception

Tags: java, date, parsing, datetime, zoneddatetime

I am trying to convert string to ZonedDateTime.

I have tried following:

```
SimpleDateFormat zonedDateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS Z");   
zonedDateTimeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); 

long timeMs = zonedDateTimeFormat.parse("2017-07-18T20:26:28.582+03:00[Asia/Istanbul]").getTime();
```

It gives `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date`

How can I parse the following string into ZonedDateTime

```
2017-07-18T20:26:28.582+03:00[Asia/Istanbul]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `java.time` API has many inbuilt-formats that simplify parsing and formatting process. The String you are trying to parse is in the standard [ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME) format. So, you could parse it easily in the following way and then get the milliseconds from the epoch:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(
                        "2017-07-18T20:26:28.582+03:00[Asia/Istanbul]", 
                        formatter);  // prints 2017-07-18T20:26:28.582+03:00[Asia/Istanbul]
long timeInMs = zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

Answer (score 2):

[`ZonedDateTime.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) seems to be designed to handle the exact string you provided. There is no need to go through the old `SimpleDateFormat`

Answer (score 2):

For ZonedDateTime we need to use `ZonedDateTime.parse` method with `DateTimeFormatter`. If I am not wrong you have an `ISO` date:

```
 ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(
         "2017-07-18T20:26:28.582+03:00[Asia/Istanbul]",
         DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME
 );
 System.out.println(zonedDateTime); //2017-07-18T20:26:28.582+03:00[Asia/Istanbul]
```

You can use either [`ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME) or [`ISO_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_DATE_TIME). Both are able to parse a date-time with offset and zone.

Comment: You are unfortunately wrong. It is NOT an ISO-format because of the trailing zone identifier in square brackets (but is nevertheless called "ISO_..." in the API, with the small explanatory note in the javadoc: "The section in square brackets is not part of the ISO-8601 standard.").

Comment: @MenoHochschild thanks a lot for your clarification. I wasn't sure about it.